# docker-compose v3.2: cannot create conatiner (...) no such file or directory when using volume long syntax

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm stuck with this problem. I'm trying to mount a volume using docker-compose long syntax but I'm getting the following error:

`ERROR: for nextcloud  Cannot create container for service nextcloud: failed to mount local volume: mount D:/nextcloud:/var/lib/docker/volumes/nc_nextcloud/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory`

Any ideas on why this is happening? I'm using version 3.2 and here's the code snippet:

```
volumes:
  db:
  nextcloud:
    driver: local
    driver_opts: 
        type: none
        device: D:/nextcloud
        o: bind
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these options aren't supported in Windows:

> The built-in local driver on Windows does not support any options.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options